# Docker instance connect to local Mongo: can't bind to address

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu

I have a dockerized (NodeJS) app that uses MongoDB.
In my local environment (Mac OS) I can run my container with the command

```
docker run -e MONGO_URL='mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/mydb' -p 8070:8000 -p 27017:27017 -d myimage:8933f
```

It works fine, it connects to a local MongoDB instance (which is not dockerized, it is a standard installation).

The problem is when I try to run the same image in an Ubuntu server. It has too an MongoDB running on port 27017.
When I try to run the image with the same command, it outputs:

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   connectivity on endpoint priceless_cartwright
>   (4a44248e01133f837144196943f6e034cb1a701a2bf783cde6e4996ea4889e4d):
>   Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:27017: bind: address
>   already in use

I can't figure out what may be happening. I tried to start a MongoDB with Docker with another port (27117) and change the connecting port in my docker run command, but the problem is the same.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

According to your statement, you already have a container running MongoDB on port 27017.

```
docker run -e MONGO_URL='mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/mydb' -p 8070:8000 -p 27117:27017 -d myimage:8933f
```

This won't work because you're trying to bind 27117 to 27017, but that port is already listening to your mongoDB container.

Comment: There is no container running on 27017. What runs in 27017 is the MongoDB itself (mongodb is running on this port).

Comment: BTW, there was a typo in my piece of code. The correct is -p 27017:27017. I'm trying to connect the "container" port 27017 with the 27017, that is where the mongo db server is running.

Comment: Yeah but 27017 is already being used by mongoDB. 

You can't map a host port that's already open to an instance of mongoDB, to map it to a container.

Comment: I'm wondering why it works in my local environment (there is too an MongoDB running in 27017 and I can connect to it). Anyway, do you know what is the best way to connect a Docker container to a MongoDB?

Comment: @ChristianBenseler - are you saying that on one computer you have MongoDB installed and running listening on port 27017, and on the same computer you have Docker attempting to spin up a container with a dependency on host port 27107 for a MongoDB inside that container using the containers port 27017?  If so, turn off the local MongoDB then try your Docker command to start up the container to verify this port resource contention.